# How do I set gvim as the default editor in loki?

Tags: settings, release-loki, switchboard

I've compiled vim from source following [these instructions](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/wiki/Building-Vim-from-source) (except I did not specify a prefix to install it to the default location viz. /usr/local) and also ran the following:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/editor editor /usr/local/bin/gvim 1
sudo update-alternatives --set editor /usr/local/bin/gvim
```

and then confirmed that it's been set as the default using

```
sudo update-alternatives --config editor
```

However, I still don't get the option to select gvim as a text editor in `Settings > Applications > Default`.

Answer (score 3):

You can select it on Settings>Applications on the Default tab from the "Text Editor" menu.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to change the default application for a file type is to **`right-click on any of such file type > Properties > Open with`**.

[image: Properties]

If you click on "Other Application", you can **"Set as default"** from the list of Recommended Applications.

[image: Recommended]

Now if your issue is that `gvim` isn't even showing in these menus, try purging your old install and trying again with: **`sudo apt install vim-gnome`**